# How to change parent of mxCell

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I am trying to change the parent of an mxCell during runtime but with no luck. 
Here is the scenario. 
Two swim lanes are added to the graph.
Each swim lane has a shape as a child.
when one of the shapes from any of the swimlane is moved to the other swimlane (drag and drop) the parent is not updated by default.
So in the code I am handling the CELLS_MOVED event and within the handler, trying to assign the parent to the cell that was moved.

childCell.setParent(parentCell);

Just to make sure that the change gets updated, I am also embedding the code within begin and end update functions.

During debug I see that the child's parent got updated. But when I try to delete the parent the newly added child cell is not deleted. On debugging I found that the shape lost its parent id again.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be handled automatically. What is the value of graph.dropEnabled? If that does nothing, try changing the parent using model.add https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/model/mxGraphModel-js.html#mxGraphModel.add

Comment: graph.setDropEnabled(true); this was missing and adding this solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: Is there any way to exclude swimlanes from dropEnabled? Now I see that swimlanes when moved are being added as a child to another swimlane which is incorrect.

Comment: Have you tried graph.setSwimlaneNesting(false) or overriding graph.getDropTarget? BTW: The API specification for mxGraph is at https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/index-txt.html

Comment: Yes. I tried setSwimlaneNesting and it worked. So here is the answer to my question. graph.setDropEnabled(true); and graph.setSwimlaneNesting(false) is the correct set of values I need to apply to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call the model's add function as follows.

```
graph.getModel().add(parent, child, index); // index is optional here
```